# Add private field from abstract class to migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an abstract base class with a private field, which i would like to add to my database for every inheritating class. I am currently getting the following error

**The property 'BaseField' is not a declared property on type 'ChildClass'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.**

Here is my current (and desired) setup :

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
     private string BaseField{ get; set; }

     internal class BaseClassConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : BaseClass
     {
         internal BaseLogbookConfiguration()
         {
             Property(p => p.BaseField);
         }
     }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    private string ChildField { get; set; }

    internal class ChildClass : BaseClassConfiguration<ChildClass>
    {
        internal ChildClass ()
        {
            Property(p => p.ChieldField);
        }
    }

}
```

and then, in my DbContext

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ChildClass.ChildClassConfiguration());
 }
```

Upon doing add-migration my_migration, i get the error above. 
I have tried changing BaseField's access level to protected or to internal, and they both caused the same error. However, changing it to public correctly built the migration, including ChildClass's own private field.

```
   AddColumn("dbo.ChildClass", "ChildField", c => c.String());
   AddColumn("dbo.ChildClass", "BaseField", c => c.String());
```

However, i dont want classes outside of my library to be able to access to BaseField directly. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If `add-migration` has no idea it exists because it's outside of your compile, how does it know to access it?

Comment: I have `public DbSet<ChildClass> Child { get; set; }` in my DBContext, which was detecting my class fine prior. The addition of the private fields is a modification.
I also tried adding `base()` to `internal ChildClassConfiguration() : base()`, with no change in result.

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, the type `ChildClass` does not contain a field or variable named `BaseField.` It contains a field named `ChildField`.

I can see that the `BaseClass` contains a `BaseField`, but it is marked private, which means it is not inherited. If you'd like it to be inherited, mark it protected or public.

Comment: I have tried making BaseField protected, and the result does not change. Making it public works, but that exposes information i dont want to be exposed in the calling aseembly.